# Token sequence labeling

Tags: nlp, sequence

I have a task which is half a matcher and half an entity extraction. I want to label some words that in some contexts refer to some label. Named entity extraction would be the way to go, but these words do not necessarily share structure (they can be verbs, nouns... etc). I could simply use a dictionary, but I would like to use context to label them. I am having trouble finding a solution to this problem. Can NER be used for this or is this a completely different task?

To give some examples, consider that I am interested in the following category "customer acceptance". Now, these can be possible sentences: "this is a fair amount of data!" and "this condition is not fair". I want my word extractor to find only the second 'fair'.

In other words, it is like a dictionary that takes context into account.

Comment: Could you give an example? You mean that one of the categories might have entries with different POS... are these categories semantic? Syntactic? An example would help

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help. I edited the question with examples.

Comment: Thanks that example helps. So you want to match words, but only for some word-senses?

Comment: Given a word, W, how many examples of "match W in this context" and "don't match W in this context" do you expect to be able to assemble?

Comment: Less than a hundred, probably.

Comment: That’s better than 0! If 0, this is more Word Sense Induction, but as described, this is Word Sense Disambiguation. See the overview on Sebastian Ruder’s site http://nlpprogress.com/english/word_sense_disambiguation.html

Comment: Sadly the state of the art software is quite hard to install, but it works well: https://github.com/getalp/disambiguate

Comment: Sounds really nice! By the way, what are your thoughts about using POS to disambiguate? In any case, thanks for your effort!

Comment: POS will be a feature in those systems but not the only one. For example, “man” can mean “adult human male” but also “humankind as a whole”, but both of those meanings have the same POS tag